# Dictionary in python with strings as keys | Direct Lookup vs Finding if key exisits

Tags: python, string, hash, memoization, defaultdict

Well I was doing a competetive programming ques, and in that i want to memoize result when we have two strings s1 and s2

I tried three methods with python `dp = defaultdict(int)`

First

```
h = hash(s1+s2)
if(dp[h] != 0 ): return
```

Second :

```
if(dp[(s1,s2)] != 0 ): return
```

3rd:

```
if((s1,s2) in dp ): return
```

Only the 3rd case is accepted, the 1st and 2nd one's gave TLE.
To my understanding this would mean that hashing strings would be slower that just iterating over keys .
But i am not sure can anyone make it clear.

Comment: What's "TLE"...?

Comment: Frankly, the whole problem is unclear - not the question you try to solve, not your problem with the 3 code snippets you show. Check [ask].

Comment: None of these should be *significantly* slower than the other, in the grand scheme of things. How many millions of times are you iterating this for it to make a difference? Are you sure the code behaves identically in all three cases? If your program's runtime is balancing this much on knife's edge that using one or the other method here makes a difference, then there are probably other parts you should be optimising first.

Comment: @deceze, I guess it's more theoretical than practical optimization for specific code, because OP is _doing a competetive programming ques_, trying to implement own LRU cache if I understand right

Comment: @deceze, [TLE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLE) - time limit exceeded

Comment: @buran I guessed as much, but it'd still be clearer to not use random abbreviations in a question.

Comment: Looking for `s1 + s2` is not always the same as looking for `(s1, s2)` - for example if `s1 = 'a'` and `s2 = 'aa'` then `s1 + s2 == s2 + s1` but `(s1, s2)` is not the same as `(s2, s1)`